# Responsive design - dropdown menu height conflict

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, media-queries

Please firstly visit my webpage [tristans.ml/..](http://tristans.ml/SpletnaTrgovina/) and make your browser window less that 1000px wide, then open the menu and there you have my issue.
I don't know a good way to solve this problem. The code is as follows:
First the media queries in css:

```
@media all and (max-width:1000px){
    #nav_holder{
        width:100%;
        height:54px;
        z-index:2;
    }
    nav{
    }
    .first_menu{
        display:none;
    background:#161619;
    }
    .logo_b{
    top:0;
        float:right;
        display:block;
    }
    #logo{
        padding:0;
    }
    #ttrgovina{
        width: 200px;
    }
    #container{
        margin-top:54px;
    }
}
```

Then there is the html code (sorry if it's a mess):

```
<div id="nav_holder">
    <div id="logo">
        <span class="logo_b" id="nav_button"><img width="55" height="55" src="style/images/menu.png" alt="Menu"></span>
        <span class="logo_b" id="cart_button"><img width="55" height="55" src="style/images/cart.png" alt="Cart"></span>
    </div>
    <nav>
        <span id="ttrgovina">Tshop</span>
        <ul class="first_menu">
            <li>
                <a id="menu_1" href="javascript:void();">Komponente</a>
                <ul class="second_menu"></ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
</div>
```

NOTE: the code has been shortened. just li elements removed.

Would you please help me with this issue cause I am hanging on it for quite some time now. I tried also creating 2 menus, but I think this is a waste of time. If you need more data or anything else, just comment the post.

Comment: tristans.ml is just a naked directory. You should [create a Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) displaying the relevant break in behavior.

Comment: oh I am sorry, the link will get fixed now.